# I want a twitter feed to alert my iPhone

Tags: iphone, twitter, apns

On my iPhone, I'd like to get a push alert when there's a new tweet from a twitter account.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Push alert for every new tweet?

Answer (score 1):

[boxcar](http://boxcar.io/provider_list), which is a beautiful little app, offers this functionality. It's a [free download from the app store](http://boxcar.io/download).

Comment: Looks good but is broken in 5.0

Comment: Can you give some more detail about the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

You can now turn on notifications for users you follow on iOS 10 by clicking on the bell icon near the top right.